# Как прочитать данные из текстового файла и записать их в массив?

Tags: массивы, pascal

Мне дан текстовый файл со словами, каждое слово - новая строка. **Количество строк известно.** Мне необходимо каждую из этих строк сделать элементом массива и дальше работать с этими элементами. Как это сделать?

```
program slovar;

const 
  N = 7;

var
   a: array [1..N] of string;
   s: string;
   f: text;
   c: string;

begin
   assign(f, 'bd.txt');
   reset(f);
   read(f, a);
end.
```

Comment: Где у вас возникли затруднения? Добавте в вопрос код.

Comment: `TStringList.LoadFromFile`

Comment: @Igor Если это простой Паскаль, то там наверно нет `TStringList` ?

Comment: @Kromster а-а, да Delphi и в метках нет, пардон

Comment: Вы просите код, а у меня его в принципе и нет, все, что я сделал, это создал массив, файл, и обратился к этому файлу. Дальше я просто не знаю, что делать.

Comment: Добавил то, что есть.

Comment: Сейчас, для примера, в файле 8 строк.

Answer (score 1):

```
  i: integer;
begin
  assign(f, 'bd.txt');
  reset(f);
  for i := 1 to N do
  begin
    readln(f, a[i]);
  end;
  close(f);

  ...
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Максим Пожалуйста. Слева галочка - щёлк :).